# RISC OS on Raspi

Tags: riscos

I have tried Noobs on raspi and is working great although a bit slow at times ,I wish to try RISC os on RASPI , as through online communities have learnt that it is faster than other OSes for RASPI .
But really have no idea about it , I installed RISC os on 16 gb Transcend sd card , but it boots to a terminal window , Used the login and password as root , it passes through it , after that How can i start the GUI for RISC , I had to type startx for X11 on wheezy ,couldnt find the command for RISC .Also is it possible to write Gui  Apps for RISC os based on python , or C .
On wheezy i have created an app based on python , tkinter .How to go about RISC .

Comment: https://www.riscosopen.org/wiki/documentation/show/HomePage

Answer (score 1):

Weird. Mine just boots to Desktop. Try reinstalling it!

FYI, I do find Risc to be faster. It's also highly customizable, like you can change it to 256 colour mode and such. The only problem is you won't be finding any software for it!